# Create related objects after initialize another object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the below models:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :bars
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :foo
end
```

In the business logic, when initializing an object `foo` `f = Foo.new` three bars need to be initialized, too.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can:

- set an after_initialize callback that initializes the Bar instances
- set additional :autosave option on the has_many association to assure child Bar instances get saved when saving the parent foo

The code will then look like this:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars, autosave: true

  after_initialize :init_bars

  def init_bars
    # you only wish to add bars on the newly instantiated Foo instances
    if new_record?
      3.times { bars.build }
    end
  end

end
```

You can add the option dependent: :destroy if you wish Bar instances get destroyed when you destroy the parent Foo instance.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `after_create`(after calling `Foo.create`) or `after_initialize`(after calling `Foo.new`) in your `Foo.rb`

```
after_create :create_bars

def create_bars 
  3.times  do
   self.bars.create!({})
  end
end
```

Or:

```
after_initialize :create_bars

def create_bars 
  3.times  do
   self.bars.new({})
  end if new_record?
end
```

Comment: I read that in rails 4, `after_initialize` is deprecated. Is it this possible? I can't use `after_create` because this method save on database. In my case, I will save after

Comment: Actually,  this callback is called only when the object is instanciated from the database (meaning, it's a duplicate of 'after_find' callback). So, look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can define that in the `initialize` method of the `Foo` class. Initializer block will run whenever the `Foo` object gets created and you can create the related objects in that method.